# Identity for a measurable set

Tags: analysis

Let $ f: \Omega\to [0,\infty[ $ be a simple function and $ (f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a monotone increasing sequence of simple functions $ f_n: \Omega\to [0,\infty[ $ such that $ f\leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f_n $.
Assume $ f\neq 0 $ and let are $ 0<\alpha_1<\alpha_2<...<\alpha_m $ the value's of $ f $ and define the set's $$ A:=\{x\in \Omega: f(x)>0\}\\A_n:=\{x\in A:f_n(x)\geq f(x)-\varepsilon\} $$ with $ 0<\varepsilon<\alpha_1 $.

Then $$ A=\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n. $$
The inclusion $ \supseteq $ is clear for me because this follows by the construction of the set's $ A_n $. But how can I prove the other inclusion $ \subseteq $? Let be $ x\in A $.I want to show there exist's an index $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ f_n(x)\geq f(x)-\varepsilon $.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what $\alpha_i$ is. What is the definition of $\alpha_i$?

Comment: I defined it in my describtion. They are the values of $f$.

Comment: Okay. Since you write $f\not=0$, why not just let $f$ map into $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Because $ f\neq 0 $ doesn't imply $ f(x)=0 $ for all $ x\in \Omega $.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\in A$. Then by definition of $A$, $f(x)>0$. We thus have that
$$0 < \epsilon < \alpha_1 \leq f(x)\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x).$$
If the limit is $\infty$ then $x\in\cup_nA_n$ is trivial. Supposing then that it is finite, the inequalities above imply that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} [f_n(x) - f(x)] \geq 0.\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Moreover, for any integer $n$, we have the equivalence

$$f_n(x) \geq f(x) - \epsilon \iff f_n(x)-f(x) \geq -\epsilon\tag{2}\label{eq2}.$$ From \eqref{eq1} we can infer that there is some $n_0$ satisfying the RHS of \eqref{eq2}. Hence $x\in A_{n_0}$, implying the other inclusion.

Comment: Did this clarify things for you?